# Moving files into new folders in an Angular app

Tags: visual-studio-code

From the beginning, I should have neatly placed all my components in a **components** folder, just like my **services** and **models** and **directives**, but I didn't...

In a large project, is there a way of simply transferring all the scattered components and services and models and directives into such directories without having to resolve all the ensuing issues, such as changing ./componentName to ../components/componentName, or do I have to deal with the *move/relocation* manually one by one?

I thought if you move a file/folder in VSCode (by dragging) the imports would be adjusted automatically, but they don't.

I also have the **Angular Essentials** extension installed, but that doesn't do that either.

Is there a way to deal with move import adjustments automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure if there is a way to do this using the terminal (probably it exists).

But in VS code, you can simply rename the component to include the folder you want to use as a container and everything will be updated automatically.

Let's say you have some like:

[image]

And you want to move the component named 'single-value-card' to the 'visualization' folder.
Then all you have to do is to rename the component folder as shown:

[image]

And voilá:

[image]

**Note:** After renaming, VS Code will ask you if you want to apply the reference refactor. As I've answered 'Always apply the reference update' (or smth like that) it never asked me again